# Combine multiple screenshots into one

Tags: image-processing

I'd like to take lots of overlaping screenshots to capture parts of a "top-view" ancient game, and to assemble them into one big image, revealing the map during my progress.

Which software can I use to avoid doing the collage manually?
I use Linux and Windows.

The screenshots will be cleaned before use (centered on the useful part, sprites removed, etc): the pictures can be directly assembled because the overlaping parts will be strictly identical.

I already used a stitching software (autostitch), but this is for a very different need. The result with screenshots are... not very good (very distorded).

Comment: Gimp? I would do this with gimp.

Comment: Check on gis.stackexchange.com, or ask again there?

Comment: Seems "peterh - Reinstate Monica" doesn't understand "[...] avoid doing the collage manually" despite the fact it is a very simple sentence.